# How to set the rotate view 90 degree in previous state in swift?

Tags: swift

Launching Image Ok [Landscape left Ok](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBEX.png)I have rotate the view with 90 degree. and I want that view comes in start position(Original Position) How to fix this issue in swift?

[Portrait Again Not OK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPt1B.png)

Comment: What I could understand is that you have a view rotated 90 degrees but you want to show it in the original stated, meaning -90 degrees relative to the view you have. So you can just rotate 270 degrees or -90. If it is not what you want please elaborate on it.

Comment: case .landscapeLeft:
            print("Landscape left")
            
            self.scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: -124, y: 124, width: 568, height: 320)
            self.imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0 + 120, y: 87 - 120, width: 320, height: 320)
            
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30, animations: {
                self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double(M_PI_2))))
            })

Comment: case .portrait:
            print("Portrait")
            
            
            scrollView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 320, height: 568)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 87, width: 320, height: 320)
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.30, animations: {
                self.scrollView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (CGFloat(Double(-90))))
            })

Comment: I have write above code for the rotate scrollview and scroll view rotate first time at left is ok but when rotate portrait it is not rotate and height Width is Ok. What we should do for fix this issue??

Answer (score 2):

Hope this answer will help you,

```
viewExample.transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
```